# Compaq Contura 430C replacement hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, laptop, compaq

I have a working Compaq Contura 430C laptop, but its hard disk is really aging and making noises when under load.  I don't want to stress it any further and thinking of replacement and preserve the remaining life of the drive.  Can I use any modern IDE (PATA) 2.5 hard disk with this laptop?  Or should I get the specific hard drives mentioned in the manual, because otherwise it wouldn't be recognized?

Comment: You might need to keep below 528MB due to probable BIOS limits.

Comment: What size (and even better, what model) is the existing drive?

Comment: My current drive is 720MB. Based on the manual I think part number is 189156-001.

Comment: [EZ-Drive](https://www.philscomputerlab.com/western-digital.html#) is your friend with it you can use larger drives however I would not go beond 40GB (some HDDs have jumper switch to force 40GB limit they are the best for you)... However Compaq BIOS is one of the worst I ever seen so you might have really hard time to get new HDD recognized